# Using email trigger extension firebase in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've added the extension for email trigger for Firebase. I have this function:

```js
firestore
  .collection("profiledata")
  .doc(user.uid)
  .update({
    accountStatus: "active",
  })
  .then(() => {
    //here, I want to put the Firebase code
    props.history.push("/clients");
  });
```

however, when I put the Firebase code into it:

```js
firestore
  .collection("gianluca@piersolutions.ca")
  .add({
    to: "contact@piersolutions.ca",
    message: {
      subject: "Hello from Firebase!",
      text: "This is the plaintext section of the email body.",
    },
  })
  .then(() => console.log("Queued email for delivery!"));

props.history.push("/clients");
```

it looks like this in my IDE:

[image]

I don't know why it is not allowing me to put this code here! How do I fix?

Comment: Can you share your extension config? To which collection you should write to trigger the email sending?

Comment: @RenaudTarnec I've actually edited my question. It inserted into the firestore collection. But it gave the error `Error: Failed to deliver email. Expected at least 1 recipient.` but I have one recipient? I am using the Trigger Email firebase extension. https://firebase.google.com/products/extensions/firestore-send-email

Comment: See my answer. You need to use the collection you have declared when configuring the extension?

Answer (score 2):

As explained in the following [article](https://medium.com/firebase-tips-tricks/how-to-send-e-mails-using-firebase-extensions-a10d7cd685c2), to send an email via the extension you need to create a document in the collection that you have configured in the "Email documents collection" field.

[image]

So, if this collection is named `mail`, as shown in the above example, you need to do as follows:

```
firestore.collection("profiledata").doc(user.uid)
    .update({
        accountStatus: "active"
    })
    .then(() => {
        return firestore.collection('mail').add({
            to: ['someone@example.com'],
            message: {
                subject: 'Hello from Firebase!',
                text: 'This is the plaintext section of the email body.',
                html: 'This is the <code>HTML</code> section of the email body.',
            }
        });
    })
    .then(() => {
     
        props.history.push('/clients')

    });
```

Comment: yes, I did that, and I got this error: `Error: Invalid login: 535 5.7.139 Authentication unsuccessful, SmtpClientAuthentication is disabled for the Tenant. Visit https://aka.ms/smtp_auth_disabled for more information. [CH2PR07CA0052.namprd07.prod.outlook.com]`

Comment: You have a problem for connecting to the email provider. I cannot help you much more, as it is specific to the email provider. You should find some more info with: https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox-b-d&q=Error:+Invalid+login:+535+5.7.139+Authentication+unsuccessful,+SmtpClient+Authentication+is+disabled+for+the+Tenant&spell=1&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjmpYuEmPnvAhWDgf0HHa2mAzMQBSgAegQIARAw&biw=1680&bih=953